# Calculate the transformation of a PCA in R?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, pca

I'm looking for the weights that represent the mapping from a dataset to its PCs. The aim is to set up a "calibrated" fixed space e.g. of three sorts of wine and when new observations e.g. a new sort of wine is introduced it can be allocated within the previously calibrated space without changing the fixed PC values. So new observations can be allocated appropriately by executing the transformation applied to the first three sorts.

```
 library(ggbiplot)
 data(wine)
 wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
 print(ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups =   wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
```

**Edit:** The wine dataset is split into training data, to get what I called a calibrated space.

```
samp <- sample(nrow(wine), nrow(wine)*0.75)
wine.train <- wine[samp,]
```

Then subset a dataset to be validated using the training data e.g.

```
wine.valid <- wine[-samp,]

#PCA on training data
wine.train.pca <- prcomp(wine.train, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
#use the transformation matrix from the training data to predict the validation data
pred <- predict(wine.train.pca, newdata = wine.valid)
```

Subsequently, how to represent the calibrated space resulting from the training and the validation/testing data transformed is addressed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603268/how-to-plot-training-and-test-validation-data-in-r-using-ggbiplot).

Comment: You can't compare the PC coordinates from wine.pca with pred because they have a different number of samples. Plus, it doesn't make sense because wine.pca already contains the coordinates in pred. You have now clarified that you actually want to predict the wine category, so I think my follow up suggestion of randomForest is a good option.

Comment: Sorry been afc - thanks @Marcinthebox for you responses and explanation again! I had a typo in my example above, as it was ncol(wine) instead of nrow(wine). Furthermore there should be no class given in the prediction data, so I changed those to "unknown".

Comment: Just came across this nice answer, again by @Marcinthebox, clarifying an analogous problem which can be found here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-to-use-r-prcomp-results-for-prediction

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603268/how-to-plot-training-and-test-validation-data-in-r-using-ggbiplot) provides a follow up answer for the plotting of the training and validation dataset in ggbiplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with the `predict` function for `prcomp`. Below I show the performance by splitting up your wine data into two parts; training and validation datasets. The prediction of the validation PCA coordinates using the the prcomp-fitted PCA on the training set is then compared with those same coordinates as derived from the full dataset :

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)

# pca on whole dataset
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

# pca on training part of dataset, then project new data onto pca coordinates 
set.seed(1)
samp <- sample(nrow(wine), nrow(wine)*0.75)
wine.train <- wine[samp,]
wine.valid <- wine[-samp,]
wine.train.pca <- prcomp(wine.train, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
pred <- predict(wine.train.pca, newdata = wine.valid)

# plot original vs predicted pca coordinates
matplot(wine.pca$x[-samp,,1:4], pred[,1:4])
```

[image]

You can also look at the correlation between the predicted and original coordinates, and see that they are very high for the leading PCs:

```
# correlation of predicted coordinates
abs(diag(cor(wine.pca$x[-samp,], pred[,])))
#       PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4       PC5       PC6       PC7       PC8       PC9      PC10 
# 0.9991291 0.9955028 0.9882540 0.9418268 0.9681989 0.9770390 0.9603593 0.8991734 0.8090762 0.9326917 
#      PC11      PC12      PC13 
# 0.9270951 0.9596963 0.9397388
```

#### Edit:

Here is an example of classification using `randomForest`:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine$class <- wine.class

# install.packages("randomForest")
library(randomForest)

set.seed(1)
train <- sample(nrow(wine), nrow(wine)*0.5)
valid <- seq(nrow(wine))[-train]
winetrain <- wine[train,]
winevalid <- wine[valid,]

modfit <- randomForest(class~., data=winetrain, nTree=500)
pred <- predict(modfit, newdata=winevalid, type='class')
```

The importance of each variable can be returned in the following way:

```
importance(modfit) # importance of variables in predition
#                MeanDecreaseGini
# Alcohol               8.5032770
# MalicAcid             1.3122286
# Ash                   0.6827924
# AlcAsh                1.9517369
# Mg                    1.3632713
# Phenols               2.7943536
# Flav                  6.5798205
# NonFlavPhenols        1.1712744
# Proa                  1.2412928
# Color                 8.7097870
# Hue                   5.2674082
# OD                    6.6101764
# Proline              10.7032775
```

And, the prediction accuracy is returned as follows:

```
TAB <- table(pred, winevalid$class) # table of preditions vs. original classifications
TAB
# pred         barolo grignolino barbera
#   barolo         29          1       0
#   grignolino      1         30       0
#   barbera         0          1      27

sum(diag(TAB)) / sum(TAB) # overall accuracy
# [1] 0.9662921
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! To my understanding (still slightly wet behind my R ears) it points in the right direction but my aim is slightly different - I'll rephrase it above for clarification.

Comment: I think you would benefit from a classification model (e.g random forests). I've added an example along the lines [shown here](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2014/04/decision-making-trees-and-machine.html) for prediction of species in the iris dataset.

Comment: I think your first explanation already full fills the mission. Just had a friend explaining it to me in more detail and I finally got my head around it. I'll edit the presentation of the problem again to make it clear. 

The follow up problem is how to plot the predicted and the training data nicely e.g. with ggbiplot, but might be another topic.

Comment: Glad it's understandable now. The plotting question should probably go to a new question -although I imagine you can find related questions on the site.

Comment: There's still some obscurities, why is wine.pca comparable with pred: 

`matplot(wine.pca$x[-samp,1:4], pred[,1:4])`

and wine.train not:

`matplot(wine.train.pca$x[,1:4], pred[,1:4])` 

 _Error in ... 'x' and 'y' must have same number of rows._

All three have different numbers of rows though:

`str(wine.pca$x) ... num [1:178, 1:13] ...`

`str(wine.train.pca$x) ... num [1:133, 1:13]...` 

`str(pred) ... num [1:45, 1:13] ...`

Comment: The first example used 75% for the training and 25% for the validation. These rows were defined with `samp`, so `wine.pca$x[-samp,1:4]` is only selecting the same rows as pred.

Comment: Ok, as stated in your first example, to plot original vs predicted pca coordinates I do: `matplot(wine.pca$x[-samp,1:4], pred[,1:4])` which is then the 25% validation data plotted against pred and both are num [1:45, 1:4] - It's getting brighter already ;)